# is it possible to use an object structure to access functions such that code completion is easier to find the correct function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a long list of functions in some libraries and I would like to access them through a structure when writing code.
I tried to do the following:

```js
function fn1(){doSomething}
function fn2(){doSomething}
//more functions...
function fn100(){doSomething}


group1 = {
"set1":{"item1": fn1,
        "item2": fn2,
        "item3": fn3
       }
//more sets...
}

command = {
"group1": group1,
"group2": group2,
"group3": group3
}
```

The aim being to write

```
command.group1.set1.item1()
```

While the above approach sort of works, it doesn't provide `this` to the function.

Is there any way to create a pattern that allows this to be done properly and passes `this`

EDIT:
I am aiming to pass the original `this` to the final function which basically means chaining `this` through the object structure.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't provide `this` to the function"? Currently, the `this` will be bound to the set in which the function resides. What do you expect `this` to be bound to when you call the method?

Comment: you can use call and apply to pass this when executing function to pass reference of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) for binding any `this` you want to a functions

Comment: yes bind appears to be the right advice, however, bind only applies to functions and not to the objects I was using to create a "navigation" hierarchy. It looks like I will need to modify my approach and use a function/class instead of the object structure.